# Why isn't my high score saving on Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am having trouble with this. It does not save the current score as the high score when it should as it is greater than 0. I want the code to save the score then when I play again the high score is updated. All the relevant code is below. Thanks :) I am new to Python/Pygame

```
def highScores(high_score):
    intro = True
    while intro == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

    gameDisplay.fill(black)
    font1 = pygame.font.SysFont('gillsans', 35, bold = True)
    font2 = pygame.font.SysFont('gillsans', 20)
    title = font1.render("High Score", True, white)
    gameDisplay.blit(title, (200,100))
    first = font2.render("Your high score is: "+str(high_score), True, white)
    gameDisplay.blit(first, (70,200))

    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, (350, 400, 100, 45))
    button("Back",350, 400, 100, 45,"back")
    pygame.display.update()

def highScore(count):
    high_score = get_high_score(count)
    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont('gillsans',30)
    text = smallText.render("High Score: "+str(high_score), True, white)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (420,0))

def get_high_score(count):
    high_score = count
    try:
        high_score_file = open("high_score.txt", "r")
        high_score = int(high_score_file.read())
        #high_score_file.close()
        #return high_score
    except:
        pass
    if count >= high_score:
        return high_score
        save_high_score()

def save_high_score(count):
    try:
        high_score_file = open("high_score.txt", "w")
        high_score_file.write(str(count))
        #high_score_file.close()
        #return high_score
    except:
        pass
    if count >= high_score:
        return high_score
        save_high_score()
```

Comment: In `def get_high_score(count):` it looks like you are returning, before you can execute `save_high_score()` and you should include the parameter `count` when you execute it. i.e. `save_high_score(count)`. Put a few `print` commands in your code to show what you are executing and when.

Comment: Don't use bare `except`s, since that hides every possible error and makes your program very hard to debug. Always specify the exception that you expect like `except IOError:` and then print a message for the user. Also, keep the `try` clauses as short as possible.

Answer (score 2):

In `get_high_score`, you are returning before saving:

```
    return high_score
    save_high_score()
```

You could just reverse the two statements:

```
    save_high_score()
    return high_score
```

If you really need the `save_high_score` call in `save_high_score`, you will have to refactor your code. Doing that will do an unintended recursion.